# I am new in mvc4 i write a code for taking table's values in the view directly using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        //Employee employee = new Employee()
        //{ 
        //    EmployeeId = 101,
        //    Name = "rehan",
        //    Gender = "Male",
        //    City = "Hafizabad"
        //};
        //return View(employee);

        EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
      Employee employee=  employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);
        return View(employee);
    }
```

I can't got the table's values in view

```
 namespace NewMvcDemo.Models
{
[Table("tblEmploee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

}
}
```

And this is my view
       @model NewMvcDemo.Models.Employee

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeDetails";
}

   <h2>EmployeeDetails</h2>
   <table style="font-family:Arial">
   <tr>
      <td>EmployeeId</td>
      <td>@Model.EmployeeId</td>

</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>EmployeeName</td>
    <td>@Model.Name</td>

</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>EmployeeGender</td>
    <td>@Model.Gender</td>

</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>EmployeeCity</td>
    <td>@Model.City</td>

</tr>


</table>
<ul>
       @foreach (string strcountry in ViewBag.Countries)
    { 
        <li>@strcountry</li>
        }

        </ul>
```

So please help me to use the entity framework in the write way
There is the error during the rendring.There is no compilation error

Comment: _There is the error_? WHAT ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag.Countries never defined in your controller!

I suggest you to use ViewModel to pass your data from controller to view.